# How can i upload my file from MsSql Server to WinForm using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, devexpress, xtrareport

How can i upload my file from MsSql Server to WinForm using Entity Framework? My file is ReportFile(REPX) and i want that: if i click to button my Report file is open. And do it with EF.
Please help me.

My code is here:

```
public partial class frmPrint: DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    DbEntities1 _db;
    public frmPrint(tblInfo tbl, DbEntities1 db)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _db = db;

        if (tbl != null)
        {
            tblInfoBindingSource.DataSource = tbl;
        }
    }

 private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog LoadFile= new OpenFileDialog();
        LoadFile.Filter = "REPX (*repx.*) | *.repx*";
        if (LoadFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filename = LoadFile.FileName;
            label1.Text = filename;
            TblBilgi tbl = tblInfoBindingSource.Current as TblInfo;

            byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

            tbl.ReportName = label1.Text;
            tbl.Report= file;
            _db.TblInfo.AddOrUpdate(tbl);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved.");
        }
    }
    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As I understand that you want to save and retrieve reports from the database. To implement this functionality please follow the suggested approach on DevExpress forum:

[save and retrieve xtrareports in database](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T609927/how-to-handle-report-loading-from-database)

```
Private Sub BarButtonItem3_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles BarButtonItem3.ItemClick  
        'save report to database  
        Dim rptStream As New IO.MemoryStream  
        Me.xrDesignMdiController1.ActiveDesignPanel.Report.SaveLayoutToXml(rptStream)  

        rptStream.Position = 0 'Add this line  

        Dim r As New IO.StreamReader(rptStream)  
        Dim strRpt As String = r.ReadToEnd()  
        'get next rptID  
        Dim nxtID As Integer = GetNextValue(2, "tblReports", "rptID", 0)  
        'insert tblReports record  
        RunSQL(2, "Insert into tblReports (rptID, rptName, rptDef) SELECT " & nxtID & " as expr1, 'New Report (" & nxtID & ")' as expr2,'" & strRpt & "' as expr3")  
        'open frmReports with this item  
        Dim fRpt As New frmReports  
        frmReports.intID = nxtID  
        fRpt.ShowDialog()  
    End Sub
```

References:
[How to handle report loading from database](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T609927/how-to-handle-report-loading-from-database)